# OS X Print a PDF without the background image

Tags: macos, pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat, preview

Using either Preview or Acrobat Pro, is there a way to print a PDF without the background image?

I know that in Acrobat Pro I can save the PDF as a Word document without the background but that's tedious and sometimes the PDF does not "translate" into a Word document properly.  In fact, this conversion rarely works for me and I end up with gobblygook.

For instance, look at the difference between these 2 files.  I compressed both the original PDF and the Word document Acrobat Pro converted. http://www.filedropper.com/oronci

If anyone knows of a way to simply print the text without including the background image, I would be extremely appreciative.  If there's also a way to keep the non-background image I'd be stoked, however if it means printing without either image that's okay.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Generally Acrobat and Preview are simply viewers for PDF files. Due to this, the standard versions of said softwares do not posses any way of really editing the files they open. I Know that  Acrobat Pro X has some of these features, but even for the software's price, these features are quite limited.

Comment: I have Acrobat Pro X 10.1.8 and it doesn't seem to have this option.  Is there another app that could do this for me?

Comment: I Know that there are some softwares that posses the same capabilities as word and other authoring software, except for PDFs, but they can also corrupt your PDF in the process and additionally often cause lots of money. I Would assume that if you have a copy of Acrobat Pro X then you also have access to the rest of the adobe software, and i'm pretty sure that if you have InDesign then that should work for achieving the removal of the background image from said PDF.

Comment: Er, actually, it seems that CS5 doesn't have the feature of opening PDFs directly. I cannot test CC or CS6 as I do not have them on the computer I am currently using, but they may have this feature.

Comment: If you are willing to wait until later today, I would probably be able to complete the removal of the background image for you and put it in a separate PDF from the PDF that has the text, if you would like.

Comment: It's okay, I'll just bring up the pdf page on my iPad rather than printing it

Comment: If thats what's good for you, then alright.

Answer (score 1):

How would any PDF-Reader know that a certain Image is a "background-Image" and should be removed in printing opposed to any other image? The only way would be to remove the image using your favourite PDF-Editor.

For that you can use Adobe Acrobat. Open the tools-drawer and select 'Content'. There you should have a tool called 'Edit Objects'. You can use that to select any object (your background-image for instance) and use the delete-key to remove that object from the file.